# How to increase font size of loading icon using fontaweseome

Tags: javascript

How to change loading jqgrid icon with fontawesome icon?I am able to get that icon but size is by default it is displaying so how to increase the size of fontawesome icon? I have written following code

```
$grid = $("#list1");
$pager = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").find(".loading")
        .removeClass("ui-state-default ui-state-active")
        .addClass("fa fa-spinner");
```

Even tried by giving class as `fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw` .I have not written any CSS for that jqgrid loading .Hence not getting how to do that.

Using jqgrid version `4.7`.  Fiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/w26n2be0/

Comment: can you provide a fiddle by generating the issue?

Comment: don't know how to do that!!

Comment: check this: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @MahediSabuj, when you create a fiddle, you need to click on the SAVE button at the top left corner of the page and then share the link.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w26n2be0/

Answer (score 1):

Simple CSS should do it:

```
.fa-spinner{
font-size: 40px !important;
}
```

change the *40px* to any font size you like.

The CSS above should work and the only reason it might not work is that IF there are other CSS that override the this CSS OR you have this CSS code above/before other CSS styling in your page.

You could also have something like this:

```
$grid = $("#list1");
$pager = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").find(".loading")
        .removeClass("ui-state-default ui-state-active")
        .addClass("fa fa-spinner")
        .css('font-size', '40px !important');
```

Comment: provide a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fa-lg`, `fa-2x`,  `fa-3x`,  `fa-4x`,  `fa-5x` in class definition

```
$grid = $("#list1");
$pager = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").find(".loading")
        .removeClass("ui-state-default ui-state-active")
        .addClass("fa fa-spinner fa-3x");
```

Comment: Some other css classes may override the current css class

Comment: @Dr.Geek that is what I think... OP, if you inspect the element in the console, you would be able to see what's going on and why your CSS doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidHope when we inspect element it shows like <div id="load_list1" class="loading fa fa-spinner" style="display: none;"></div>  That means it is not considering the class as fa fa-spinner instead of that it is considering loading fa fa-spinner

Comment: @Aishwarya, 'it is not considering the class as fa fa-spinner instead of that it is considering loading fa fa-spinner'. both classes you mentioned are the same.